# Automatically change JavaScript function value

Tags: php, javascript

Here is my problem.. I have some JavaScript that I want to run, however I need it to be unique each time it gets inserted. I tried adding a variable to it that would change it, however it only changes it on the first call/display. Here is the script:

```
     <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    function validate_f( )
                    {
                    var x=document.forms[\"fill\"][\"textfield\"].value
                    if (x==null || x==\"\")
                      {
                      alert(\"Field cannot be empty\");
                      return false;
                      }
                    }
                    </script>
```

The actual form code is:

```
                    echo "<td width=\"10%\">
                <form method=\"POST\"action=\"$actual_link\" id=\"fill\" onsubmit=\"return validate_f( );\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"{$data['id']}\" name=\"id\">
                <input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" class=\"BUTTON_INPUT\" name=\"url\" value=\"\" id=\"textfield\">
                </td>
                <td width=\"1%\">
                <input type=\"Submit\" class=\"BUTTON_FILL\" name=\"fill\" value=\"\">
                </form>
```

The problem is that form gets echoed multiple times with different links, but the script will only work the first time. So my only solution I could think of was to have the JavaScript echoed along with the form and have the function name changed on both the script & the form.

I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense, so basically I need "function validate_f( )" & "onsubmit=\"return validate_f( );\"" to change with each repeat/echo ..

Comment: There is no point echoing the script block multiple times (assuming the blocks are identical) as each one will *replace* the previous. Can you show more code? not just the output, the code that generates it too.

Comment: That is why I wanted the script to be unique for each echo, I just don't know how to go about doing that. I updated the code to show the entire form after the echo, hope that helps & appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: the id attribute of html elements *must* be unique (if you loop through your provided code you will have multiple "fill" id's) @TheBrain's answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution for this, and thought I would share it in case someone comes across this. But basically the form that is being echoed/repeated did get unique data on each time it repeated.. So basically I took that unique value and put it as the function & the form id.. It is pretty simple now that I look back at it, I just had to think really hard about how to get something unique that changed. Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 2):

if your text field is in every form you can use only one generic function like this that will work for all forms no matter their id

```
  function validate_f() {
      var x = this['textfield']
      if (!x || !x.value) {
          alert("field cannot be empty")
          return false
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the form id, its with the java script. Even when using the modified script you sent me the same issue happens. The Javascript is applied to the first form/text field. 

Problem is I want the script to not look for text in the first form, it should work for the form/texfield that a person filled. But since I have the same form being repeated the first form/textfield always has to contain text.